# When attaching doc in Windows 7, list not in alpha order

Tags: windows-7, email

Ok, I know I'm a dinosaur still using Windows 7 (hey, it's an old computer at work). Finally figured out how to order document folders in alpha order - BUT, when I go to attach something in an email, it comes up in a totally random order and I can see no way to fix that. Takes forever to find the file I want to attach.

Comment: What is your question?  The settings for the dialog your talking about are different then the settings for windows explorer.  There are many things about the the dialog,  that can be controlled by, the program that displays it.

Comment: @sparkerart do you wish to know why and how to stop documents uploaded to an eMail account from moving into another display order?

Answer (score 0):

Ramhound is correct that the dialog boxes will be different depending on how you are accessing your email (Outlook, Gmail, etc.), but normally they all work very similarly.  When you click to add an attachment and the dialog box opens, you should be able to order the files alphabetically by clicking on the "Name" heading.  If it orders "Z-A," simply click again and it will order "A-Z."

Comment: Thank you, did not realize that you could click on the "name" heading when adding an attachment. This has worked!

Comment: @sparkerart I know this was over a year ago, but could you please accept and upvote this answer to help fellow travelers find answers to their questions? Thank you, glad I could help! :)